# Characterize the preimage of $\mathbb{Q} \cap \{ x \mid x > 0\}$ under $\exp$?

Tags: reference-request, exponential-function

An almost trivial characterization for a real number $a$ to be taken to be a rational number $>0$ by the exponential function $\exp$ is that $a = \log \xi - \log \eta$ for some integers $\xi, \eta > 0$. But I am after some perhaps known results that give more surprising equivalences? Preferably an analytical one.

A related problem is about rational values of trigonometric function. The [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem) and its neighboring results give some insight about it, for example. I would like some similar results for the exponential functions.

Comment: Do you mean something like it's the additive subgroup or $\mathbb R$ _freely generated_ by the logarithms of primes?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Oh thanks. I was interested primarily in an analytical characterization.

Comment: What do you mean by an "analytical" characterization?

Comment: @RobArthan, I may not be able to define it; but I would say it is used to distinguish from other possible angles to think of the present question. So here being analytical perhaps means being not geometric nor algebraic :). Still not precise. Let us leave it there to the extent that no answer would suffer from this deliberate ambiguity.